# Hiding Ionic loader when navigation ends problem

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

**Hi All**,

I have a problem related to hiding the loader after navigation ends
So here is my code below and I will explain the main scenario

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private utilities: Utility) {

    this.routerEventListener();
  }

  routerEventListener() {
    let loader;
    this.router.events
      .subscribe(async (event) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
          loader = await this.utilities.presentLoader();
        }
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof NavigationError) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            loader?.dismiss();
          }, 400); // This is how i fixed the problem am having
        }
      });
  }
```

- when navigation between tabs(routes) the ionic loader takes some time to be initialized
- the NavigationEnd event is called even before the loader is initialized (So loader still undefined)

So as a conclusion the loader will not be dismissed

So how should I overcome this problem in a way different than what I did using setTimout